# Has Variant behavior changed in Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, variant

In Delphi 10.3, I had written some Excel automation code.  I used variants.  When the routine was finished, I cleared and freeAndNil the Variant...

```
  VarClear(arrData);
  FreeAndNil(arrData);
```

This compiled and ran fine.  I have just upgraded to D11, i.e. Alexandria.  This code now gives an error.  ... Incompatible Type: TObject and Variant.

I rewrote this portion of code to be:

```
  VarClear(arrData);
  arrData.Free;
```

This compiles, and at first glance, seems to run fine.  Is this the proper way to clear/dispose of variants in Alexandria?

Comment: I don't have D11,  but based on your description, they redefined `FreeAndNil(var obj)` to  `procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj:TObject)`.
Now, since `Free` is a method of TObject and unrelated to variant, unless they added helpers for variants that introduce a "free" method, that looks awfully wrong to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The signature of `FreeAndNil()` was indeed changed, in Delphi 10.4, to be exact:

https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2020-may-delphi-104-rtl.html

> We updated the signature of the FreeAndNil procedure, to avoid its use with interface references **and other unsupported data types**. It is now declared to require a reference to a TObject:
>
> `procedure FreeAndNil(const [ref] Obj: TObject); inline;`
>
> **This means that incorrect usage of FreeAndNil will now cause a compiler error.** In the past, incorrect usage would not be caught, leading to difficult bugs. Note that although the parameter is declared as const, the by-reference variable is indeed modified.

It is wrong to try to `Free()` a `Variant` in the first place.  That has *never* worked, and should *never* have been in your code in the first place.  Under the old definition, `FreeAndNil()` would have called `TObject.Free()` on the `Variant`, which is wrong.  Under your new code, `arrData.Free;` will compile, but will invoke method dispatching at runtime to call a non-existent `Free()` method on the Excel object, which will fail.

So, just remove the `Free` altogether, it doesn't belong here.  The correct solution, in all Delphi versions, to manually reset a `Variant` to a default state is to assign [`Variants.Null`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Null) or [`Variants.Unassigned`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Unassigned) to it, eg:

```pascal
arrData := Null;
```

```pascal
arrData := Unassigned;
```

Comment: Excellent Answer!

Comment: FreeAndNil does (falsely) not complain when called in a (object type) property. This is painfully wrong, Emb has traded a bad solution  for another bad solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479148/

Answer (score 6):

Both of these code snippets are wrong. You don't call `Free` on a variant. You call `Free` on an object instance. Simply remove that line.

Comment: And before you tell me that the code used to work, it didn't. It has always been wrong and you've somehow got away with it.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable is a pointer array FreeAndNil is not the solution. but freemem

```
FreeMem(PSomeArray);
```